# wxWidgets Load Image from file

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need to load an image, but the moment I only have an absolute path:

```
StaticBitmap1 = new wxStaticBitmap(this, ID_STATICBITMAP1, wxBitmap(wxImage(_T("C:\\Users\\Jurgen\\Documents\\C++\\Dorienne-COPITRON\\copy_logo.jpg")).Rescale(wxSize(0,72).GetWidth(),wxSize(0,72).GetHeight())), wxPoint(32,24), wxSize(0,72), wxSIMPLE_BORDER, _T("ID_STATICBITMAP1"));
```

Is there a way to make it relative? instead of simple C:\Users...

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT: I managed to make it Referencial by just leaving it "copy_logo.jpg" as the path, but I have this error popping every time I run it.

[image: Debug Error Alert]

More errors keep on showing if I press NO. I have to press CANCEL all the time. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is obviously due to using invalid `wxSize`, exactly as the assert message says (have you *read* it?). I don't know what are you trying to do here but you can't use `wxSize(0, 72)`. Just call `Rescale(72, 72)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should find [wxStandardPaths](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_standard_paths.html) class useful. In particular, images used in the program are typically loaded from the directory returned by its [GetResourcesDir()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_standard_paths.html#a5514bf6288ee9f5a0acaf065762ad95d) method.

Comment: I managed to do a reference link by removing the absolute part leaving just "copy_logo.jpg". Problem is this. The logo DOES show up BUT I have this error in which I have to press CANCEL all the time
http://postimg.org/image/y41uxe1ld/

This error is followed by several other if I keep on pressing NO.